# AIX jre is not throwing any exception

Tags: java, aes, encryption-symmetric, jce

Recently i have came across a requirement to encrypt db password which is used to create connection for stand alone scheduler using `symmetric key algorithm`.

First db password is encrypted using a `java swing utility` in which i use `aes128` bit encryption and put into the properties file.
 Then in the `connection manager` class, in which connection is created,password is read from properties file and decrypted with same key. At my end i have tested on aix server in which this code is working but at the client side it is not working. It couldn't decrypt. After following statement in connection manager class, it is exiting from method without any exception.

```
pwd=AES128Encryption.decrypt(PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("PWD").toString().trim());
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with `jce.jar`. Here is my method for decryption and connection manager class where i decrypt the password.

```
protected  Connection getConnection(){

             try{

                 mcName=PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("MACHINE_NAME");
                 sid=PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("SID");
                 port=PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("DB_PORT");
                 UserName=PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("USER_NAME");
                 pwd=AES128Encryption.decrypt(PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("PWD").toString().trim());
debug("getEncrptdData||encrypted pwd::"+PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("PWD"));
                System.out.println("decrypted pwd::"+pwd);
                 tns=PAYTFHomeProperties.getProperty("TNS");
                 hostString="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+mcName+":"+port+":"+sid;
                  OracleConnectionPoolDataSourcecpds=new                 OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
                          cpds.setDriverType("thin");
                      cpds.setNetworkProtocol("tcp");
                      cpds.setServerName(mcName);
                      cpds.setDatabaseName(sid);
                      cpds.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(port));
                      cpds.setUser(UserName);
                      cpds.setPassword(pwd);


                      pc = (oracle.jdbc.pool.OraclePooledConnection)cpds.getPooledConnection();


                      connection con= (Connection)pc.getConnection();  

            } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("getConnection"+e.toString()); 
             }
         return con;
        }
```

Here is my `AES128Encryption` class decrypt method

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AES128Encryption {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        byte[] raw = "************".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
   }
```

Comment: @JunedAhsan no none at all..

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer but try to catch Throwable:

```
try {
  // do something
} catch (Throwable t) {
  t.printStackTrace();
}
```

And aslo check if you have in your classes / methods Exceptions without body like:

```
try {
   // do something
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do nothing 
}
```

Comment: Exceptions are handled. i got nothing in them.